# Capacitor Operating Temperature Range

Tags: capacitor, soldering, wave

Our .0047uF G 630 Vdc axial cap has an operating range of -40C - +85C. If the wave solder temp reaches 105C won't the cap be damaged, or possibly have an altered tolerance range?

Comment: The part data sheet likely has information what kind of soldering the part can handle and still remain in datasheet specifications. What part is it?

Answer (score 2):

Probably not. Such through-hole capacitors are generally designed to be wave soldered so the brief exposure to the wave soldering environment (preheat maybe to 100°C before it is hit with the molten solder on the leads) should not hurt it. A good datasheet should specify the recommended soldering profile. For example, [this](https://connect.kemet.com:7667/gateway/IntelliData-ComponentDocumentation/1.0/download/datasheet/R71QR41004010K) one.

[image]

Counterexample- through-hole styrene capacitors used in some audio and other applications are very sensitive to heat. The dielectric used in most film caps is polyester (Mylar), polypropylene, polycarbonate, PPS, PTFE, etc. all of which are relatively resistant to heat.

Comment: Yes, I believe these are Poly caps.

Comment: @StevenCarpenter poly-what though? All polymers are poly-something.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to read the data sheet for the capacitor, they show temperatures and many include wave soldering information. Note different manufacturers may have different ratings so read the data sheet for the part you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The cap manufacturer knows that the part will be soldered, naturally. Most cap specs such as lifetime are *after* exactly one cycle of soldering, according to the specified solder heating cycle. Capacitors (and semiconductors) should have such a soldering cycle specified in the datasheet.

The temp spec -40 to +85 refers to *continuous use* in the end application. The capacitance within this temperature range may vary as specified by the dielectric temperature curve (X5R, NP0 etc) and tolerance (+/-10% etc). If you leave the temperature range, the biggest immediate concern is not that the part may eventually break, but that the capacitance value will go out of spec.